# SQL Two duplicate tables copy data over

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a temp storage table where data gets imported in and an exact copy of that table which is the working table.

I want to be able to copy the data from temp table --> working table, however, it should only copy data which doesn't already exist (i.e. no duplicates) and then clear the temp table

**As I have to do this for quite a few tables and the tables are exactly the same, is there a way to insert the data without declaring the columns every time?**

Here is an example of my select statement which selects all rows from webshop_in (the imported data table) which are not in the webshop table:

```
select  *
from webshop_in T2 
left join [webshop] T1
on T2.[TrackingNumber] = t1.[TrackingNumber]
where t1.[TrackingNumber] is null
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this,

```
MERGE workingtable AS target
using (select all column from temptable )) as source
on target.id=source.id
WHEN NOT MATCHED then
INSERT (col1,col2,col3......... ) --workingtable
      VALUES (mention those column from source )
```